# ¿Mi encriptado no me dice la ultima palabra?

Tags: python, random, encriptación

Hola tengo un problema con un algoritmo para encriptar un texto a partir de un diccionario aleatorio generado, y es de que a la hora de que me diga como es la frase encriptada siempre le falta una palabra siempre y si es solo una palabra no pone ninguna. Porfavor necesito ayuda en ello, y muchisimas gracias por su tiempo.

```
import random

abc = 'abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚäëïöüÄËÏÖÜ'
abc_keys = abc[:]
#dicc_cifrado = dict.fromkeys(list(abc),"")
#op1 dicc_cifrado = {letra:random.choice(abc) for letra in abc}
dicc_cifrado = {letra:"" for letra in abc}

for texto in dicc_cifrado.keys():
#choice  = abc[random.randint(0,len(abc)]
choice = random.choice(abc)
#abc = "".join([l for l in abc if l!=choice])
#abc = [l for l in abc if l!=choice]
abc = abc.replace(choice,"")
dicc_cifrado[texto] = choice
print(dicc_cifrado)

values= dicc_cifrado.values()
dicc= "".join(values)

print("el abc codificado de un solo uso es:",dicc)
#El dicc que te de lo copias y pegas cuando te diga "Tu abc codificado es:"
texto=input("Tu texto: ")
if texto==texto.upper():
dicc_un_solo_uso=input("Tu abc codificado es: ")
else:
dicc_un_solo_uso=input("Tu abc codificado es: ")
Boof=int(input("Cuantas veces deseas boofearlo: "))
 Verschlüsselung=""
 for v in texto:
  if v in dicc_un_solo_uso:
 Verschlüsselung += dicc_un_solo_uso[(dicc_un_solo_uso.index(v)+Boof)%(len(dicc_un_solo_uso))]

 else:
 Verschlüsselung+=v
 print("magische verschlüsselung:",Verschlüsselung)
```

Comment: Puedes añadir una par de ejemplos con datos y lo que te debe devolver el algoritmo? Ya que hay poco contexto para saber lo que esperas del programa.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que quieres crear un diccionario aleatorio y usarlo para encriptar un mensaje. Usando tu código como referencia, te planteo lo siguiente.

#### En esta parte reduje algunas cosas, pero su funcionamiento es el mismo: generar el diccionario aleatorio: `dicc_cifrado={abc : abc_aleatorio}`. Además, la añadí un `while` para que no se repitieran las letras aleatorias en el `abc_aleatorio`.

```
import random

abc='abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚäëïöüÄËÏÖÜ'
dicc_cifrado={letra:"" for letra in abc}
choice=''

for texto in abc:
    while choice in dicc_cifrado.values():
        choice=random.choice(abc)
    dicc_cifrado[texto]=choice
```

#### Aquí se muestra el diccionario diccionario de un solo uso

```
dicc_un_solo_uso=''.join(dicc_cifrado.values()) #str con los valores del dicc
print('\nEl ABC codificado de un solo uso es:',dicc_un_solo_uso)
```

```
texto=input("Texto sin encriptar: ")
Boof=int(input("Cuantas veces deseas boofearlo: "))
Verschlüsselung=""
```

#### Esta parte es donde hace el recorrido del texto letra por letra, haciendo uso del diccionario aleatorio generado. También hace uso del `Boof`.

```
for letra in texto:             #hacer un barrido del texto letra por letra
    if letra in abc:            #si la letra existe en el ABC
        posicion=(abc.index(letra)+Boof)%len(abc)
        Verschlüsselung+=dicc_un_solo_uso[posicion]
    else:                       #sino la letra se mantiene igual
        Verschlüsselung+=letra
print("magische verschlüsselung:",Verschlüsselung)
```

**Nota:** Creo que he resumido mucho el código, pero espero que eso sea a lo que querías llegar. Saludos.